# Enabling/disabling MDiParent form after closing a .showDialog() form

Tags: vb.net, forms, mdichild

I currently have a form that is declared as NewMDIChild = frm1. Within frm1 i open a new form that is about 1/3 of the size of frm1 - this forms name is frmX. This is how I open it....

```
     Me.Enabled = False
    'Pass globals to be used in search query

    Dim frmX As New FrmX()
    frmX.ShowDialog()
```

So I include this code with a button_Click on my Frm1. Everything works just fine. What I'm trying to do is on the button click on frm1 - I'm trying to disable frm1 - show frmX in .ShowDialog. On FrmX i have a CLOSE button, so that when user clicks CLOSE on it, I am able to enabled = true the frm1 that is in the background. I trying to do it on ACTIVATED event but it doesn't recognize it. How would I do something like that...

Not sure if i have to call a function or something from frmx or if there is an event in frm1 that can be used to enabled it. I tried GotFocus, MouseHove - nothing works

Comment: If you show a dialog, why do you also have to disable any other form?

Comment: Per Spec sheet - they want the background form disabled - since even if frmX is show a dialog then all the buttons on frm1 don't look like they're disabled, there just not clickable. I'm able to disable them on button click, just wondering if i close frmX how to i envoke frm1.enable=true

Comment: If the form is disabled it wont be generating MouseHover or any other events.  Put `Me.Enabled` right after the `ShowDialog` - it will be the next line to execute when the dlg closes.  Also that dialog should be in a using block

Comment: @Plutonix works like a charm if you'd like to post as answer please do so and i'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the form is disabled, most (if not all) the events are not going to fire.  The next line to execute will be anything after the `ShowDialog()` so you can enable it there:

```
Me.Enabled = False
Using dlg As New FrmX
    dlg.ShowDialog()
End Using
Me.Enabled = True
```

Note that when a form is shown using `ShowDialog()` it is not automatically disposed, so the code uses a `Using` block to do so.